# Python __slots__ - почему нельзя использовать всегда?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос был задан после прочтения - [Usage of **slots**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots)

```
class WithSlots(object):

    __slots__ = 'static_attr'
```

Прочитав про слоты в пайтоне, о том, что они экономят память, я понял только одну вещь, что когда много экземпляров класса создается, то это выгодно(использование слотов).

И в связи с этим у меня возник такой вопрос, раз у слотов есть преимущество в виде экономии памяти, то почему нельзя его использовать всегда?

Какие проблемы создает слотс, давая взамен экономию памяти?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots?source=post_page-----72cdc2d334e----------------------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они ограничивают набор атрибутов класса - из-за чего нельзя свободно добавлять любые атрибуты и исполнять всякие безумные наследования, как многие любят. Выскочит `AttributeError`. Когда код переписываешь или как упомянули создаётся большое количество, то можно добавить слоты и ускорить работу скрипта, но чаще всего программист идёт "непроторённой" дорогой - там не до слотов.

```
import time

class Timer:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.clock()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.clock()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start

class A:
    pass

class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b',)

def my(class_):
    my_obj = class_
    my_obj.a = 10
    my_obj.b = "qwerty"
    print my_obj.a, my_obj.b

with Timer() as t1:
    for _ in range(1000):
        my(A())
with Timer() as t2:
    for _ in range(1000):
        my(B())
print('Time1: {} sec.'.format(t1.interval))
print('Time2: {} sec.'.format(t2.interval))

# Time1: 0.0264316595496 sec.
# Time2: 0.0241797159653 sec.
```